# How to filter emails/notifications from docusign

Tags: docusignapi

How to configure DocuSign API to send only notifications that pertain to the document not being viewed within 32 hours in my email/inbox?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from 'This envelope is expiring soon', there are not built-in notifications that relate to inactivity on an envelope. You would have to build a custom solution that monitors envelope status via DocuSign Connect, and then delivers notifications as desired.